For how many generations does the average human have descendants?
From what pop science tends to tell us, it seems that the distribution of descendants humans have is very uneven. Mitochondrial Eve is the ancestor of all women in our present, Ghenghis khan probably also left a lot of descendants, while quite a few human beings die without ever reproducing. It seems plausible that most people from the past are somewhere between these two extremes: they reproduce, but many generations later, they are either the ancestor of only a small proportion of all living humans, or their line may have died off completely.
When trying to wrap my head around this kind of descendant ideas, I started wondering: do most people from the past still have living descendants, or does the majority of people, given enough generations, lose their lines, while a few people have many descendants? And if the second possibility turns out to be true, mathematically there must be an average time until one's line disappears. So, if we choose a generation to be generation zero, how many generations does it take on average until 50% of the people from generation zero have no more living descendants? Has this number been estimated, or if not, what is the closest concept for which estimations have been done?
This question is about the state of affairs throughout the history of homo sapiens, without modern-day complications like changed reproductive patterns, or the risk of humanity wiping itself out.

Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/115164/contribution-of-ancestors-in-a-persons-genome-david-reichs-who-we-are-and-ho

@bob1 thank you. To clarify, in this case, I'm mostly interested in the genealogical line duration, not the genetic line duration, since your link shows that they can diverge quite a bit.

the problem with such a calculation is at least part of your sample have infinity as their number, and when oyu add anything to infinity and divide it by somthineg finite you still get infinity.

for a related nmuber that may be clase ot what you want, about 15% of a humans fail to reproduce.

@John you don't have to add something to infinity. In this kind of analysis, "average" is frequently not defined as the mean, but as the median. Or, one could calculate the rate for only those people whose line ends, and also mention their proportion. I'm aware that there are all kinds of subtle details here, so the answer won't be a simple back-of-the-envelope calculation.

@John these 15% are indeed quite interesting. Do you know how they are defined? Do they refer to the modern infertility rate, to modern rate of actually not reproducing (as in, some fertile people don't reproduce by choice or circumstances), to historical rates, to prehistorical rates? Is it 15% of people who reach adulthood, or 15% of anybody born, so including child mortality of potential parents?

Its just the rate of reproduction, how many people have offspring, its enturely a modern calculation. the issue with a median or average is about how you determine it. humans use recombination so if you look back after enough generations everyone alive in the population who reproduced is your ancestor. your tree if ancestors doubles every generation. the number you are looking for does not exist becasue humans reproduce sexually.

this may help you https://biologos.org/series/evolution-basics/articles/mitochondrial-eve-and-y-chromosome-adam

@John "everyone alive in the population who reproduced is your ancestor" - this can trivially be shown to be untrue. Let's take an ancient person A, who reproduces once and has a child B. B dies young and has no descendants. Obviously, A is not my ancestor. They have a descendant line of length 1, and B has a descendant line of length 0. Some people's descendant lines diverge and they have many descendants, other peoples' lines converge and die out.

@rumtscho I think John is referring to those who reproduce and have any ancestors. Very quickly as you go down generations your number of ancestors converges to either "everyone" or "no one". So, if you ask "For how many generations does the average human have descendants?" in terms of the average, that's not a very useful number. For one, anyone you'd meet today is going to have at most a few generations because that's all there's been time for and we haven't waited long enough to see how many they end up with.

If hypothetically that weren't a problem, then most of your observations are going to be people that either have as many as you were willing to go back, plus some that are zero, some that are 1, fewer that are 2, less still that are 3, and so on.

A better way to put it would be If you have ancestors then everyone who has decendants is your ancestor once you go back a few generations.. Of course the problem is people who don't have decendants don't leave a detectable trace, they don't leave a genetic marker. and becasue relatedness goes up and down the tree we can't tell if you leave decendants or if you don't and your siblings did. We have never found a humans remains without decendants. your asking for somthing that is impossible ot determine outside modern day records.

Completely revised answer:
First let me say, “All people living today have thousands of generations of ancestors.”
To answer your question we need to look at two time periods: historical (pre-1950) and present day (post-1950).
Historically
Only a small percentage of people either couldn’t have children or chose not to have children. For most people, having children was de rigeur. Part of this was the continuation of the family name and another part was the fact that children were necessary to be able to survive old age.
People usually had several children; however, about half of children did not survive childhood to become adults. child mortality
This means that at least half of the people born had no descendants. (One generation cutoff)
If a couple had children, then they had more grandchildren and even more great grandchildren. As an example in one family I know a couple had three children, nine grandchildren and nineteen great grandchildren.
Historically a person’s line of descent would end either with them, or within two or three generations. Those whose lineage persisted longer than three generations would probably continue to thrive and grow rather than diminish. There is a report on the descendants of the Mayflower, where there were 53 people who survived the first winter. The lowest estimate gives them three million living descendants today. Mayflower descendants
I would propose that if a person has more than three generations of descendants, the probability of their line dying out dramatically decreases.
Present Day
Since the 1950’s a much larger proportion of people are choosing not to have children. Birth rates in developed countries have fallen to unsustainably low levels. For example in Japan the birthrate has fallen from 27 per 1000 people in 1950 to 7 per 1000 today. macrotrends Japan birth rate
In America "Of all adults ages 55 to 64, 19.6% were childless, compared to 15.9% of those ages 65 to 74, and 10.9% of those 75 years and older." older childless and of adults under 50 almost half of them say they are not likely to have children.  fewer children
In the family I mentioned before, from the nineteen great grandchildren there are only six great-great grandchildren.
This means that the scenario you propose, with a person’s line dying out over generations is much more likely in the future. However, as we are now at this crisis point, there is insufficient data to provide a reasonable analysis.

alot more than thousands, anyone alive today has ancestors all the way back to the origin of life.

@John You are right of course, but the OP is asking about humans, so probably some tens of thousands.
